# Buttons are aligned horizontally but not getting focus

Tags: android

I have five buttons with same width and height. I am putting them horizontally. How the focus will change when i am moving from one button to another??

Comment: By moving you mean using a Trackpad?

Comment: Yes by moving trackpad or scrolling.

Comment: testing on emulator or device ??

Comment: Doing the Tablet apps..Emulator is Galaxy Tab and using 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar type of thing you can get [here](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/). instead of setting image directly to a button try to set .xml  to the button and image is set in that xml. create 5 xml for 5 buttons

Donot forget to vote the answer if my  response is helpful for you.

Thanks
Deepak